# How to set session variables for all the controllers in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

How do I create and access Symfony 2 session variables in my controllers.
I used like this.

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
$session->set('loginUserId',$user['user_id']);
```

I want to know how to use the above session variable in all my controllers to access.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way of using Sessions in Symfony in controller is:

setting:

```
$this->get('session')->set('loginUserId', $user['user_id']);
```

getting:

```
$this->get('session')->get('loginUserId');
```

If you use standard framework edition

Comment: If my answer was helpful could you mark it as answer for your problem?

Comment: whether this method is applicable to use those session variable in all my controller?

Comment: Yes it should be accessible in all controllers

Comment: to understand this answer ( which i think is better than mine for instant use ) , you should have wrote that $this->get('session') is actually a call to symfony2 session service, that's why you can call these variables from all of you controllers, handlers etc

Answer (score 12):

From the docs:

> Symfony sessions are designed to replace several native PHP functions.
>   Applications should avoid using session_start(),
>   session_regenerate_id(), session_id(), session_name(), and
>   session_destroy() and instead use the APIs in the following section.

and:

> While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a sessions will
>   actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to
>   read/write session data.

So sessions is started automatically and can be accessed e.g. from controllers via:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    ...
}
```

or:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    // or
    $session = $this->get('session');
    ...
}
```

than:

```
// store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
$session->set('foo', 'bar');

// get the attribute set by another controller in another request
$foobar = $session->get('foobar');

// use a default value if the attribute doesn't exist
$filters = $session->get('filters', array());
```

Answer (score 3):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

```
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

  $session = new Session();
  $session->start();

  // set and get session attributes
  $session->set('name', 'Drak');
  $session->get('name');

  // set flash messages
  $session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');

  // retrieve messages
     foreach ($session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array()) as $message) {
     echo '<div class="flash-notice">'.$message.'</div>';
  }
```