# How do I get the logged in user's id in symfony 4?

Tags: php, html, symfony, symfony4

The user can log in, but i need his id to show his profile. Since i'm working in symfony 4, the many possible answers i've found were obsolete.

Comment: Perhaps you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682743/how-to-set-session-variables-for-all-the-controllers-in-symfony2)?

Comment: Why don't you try the answers before saying they are obsolete? `$this->getUser()` is valid wether you use symfony 2 or 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

> After authentication, the User object of the current user can be accessed via the getUser() shortcut (which uses the security.token_storage service). From inside a controller, this will look like:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

    $user = $this->getUser();
}
```

The user will be an object and the class of that object will depend on your user provider.  But, you didn't tell us what user provider you are using, so I have no way of telling you, beyond this, how to get to the id itself.

One other way to get the user:

> An alternative way to get the current user in a controller is to type-hint the controller argument with UserInterface (and default it to null if being logged-in is optional):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface\UserInterface;

public function indexAction(UserInterface $user = null)
{
    // $user is null when not logged-in or anon.
}
```

> This is only recommended for experienced developers who don't extend from the Symfony base controller and don't use the ControllerTrait either. Otherwise, it's recommended to keep using the getUser() shortcut.