# Symfony 5 - Get old collection data before submit form

Tags: php, symfony, compare, clone, persist

In my symfony 5 project I would like when submitting a certain form, compare the entity before and after submission.

So keep a copy of the original entity in order to perform processing.

I've :

```php
$parametresAdmin = $entrepriseService->getParametresAdmin();

        $form = $this->createForm(ParametresAdminType::class, $parametresAdmin, [
            'entreprise' => $this->getUser()->getEntreprise(),
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $entrepriseService->updateParametres($parametresAdmin);

             return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_parametres');
        }
```

In fact, I want to get a copie of `$parametresAdmin->getTypesConges()` (which is a collection on OneToMany).

So, when the form is submitted, I want compare the old `$parametresAdmin->getTypesConges()` and the new `$parametresAdmin->getTypesConges()`.

The "$parametresAdmin->getTypesConges()" part looks like this:

[image]

I can add / modify leave types on the fly. Except that I do not want to authorize the possibility of modifying the "Balance type" field for the types of leave that already exist. There is just for those that I add that I leave the possibility in the ChoiceType. So on the front side, it's good. But on the back side, no.

But it doesn't work

What I do :

I change the "Solde initial" for the first line : [image]

But when I submit, I've the same value (the new value : 10 )

[image]

EDIT : Currently, I've now :

```php
        $parametresAdmin = $entrepriseService->getParametresAdmin();
        $typeConges = $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges();
        $oldTypesConges = clone $typeConges;

        $form = $this->createForm(ParametresAdminType::class, $parametresAdmin, [
            'entreprise' => $this->getUser()->getEntreprise(),
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $typeConges = $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges(); // update with new data
            dd($oldTypesConges, $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges());

            $entrepriseService->updateParametres($parametresAdmin);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_parametres');
        }
```

Comment: Assuming your currently posted code matches your actual code (it is easy to get confused when troubleshooting) then I suspect the problem is that $typeConges is actually an array.  PHP performs a shallow clone which means that objects inside of the array are not cloned.  So you might need to loop over $typeConges and clone each individual element.

Answer (score 3):

You should clone your data like this :

```
$typeConges = $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges();
$oldTypeConges = clone $typeConges;
// handleRequest(), isValid(), isSubmit() ...
$typeConges = $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges(); // update with new data
dd(oldTypeConges, $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges());
```

[phpdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) says about :

> When an object is cloned, PHP will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references.

Take a look at [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185934/how-do-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-php).

Comment: Yes, I tried like this too, but it still doesn't work. I've updated my first post by adding the current code. It's really weird

Comment: Could you try `spl_object_hash($oldTypeConges)` and compare value with `spl_object_hash($parametresAdmin->getTypesConges())`, if it's same so it's not the solution and we have to find out why.

Comment: I tried, and I've `0000000021b16e9700000000327f6e55` and `0000000021b16eb000000000327f6e55` so...no, it's not the same. I will update my first post to give more precisions on the goal of what I want if it can help you (first post updated with more context)

Comment: I updated my first post again with exactly what I'm doing and the results of the dump. You can see that if I change the value of the "Initial Balance" from the 1st row to "10". When I validate, I see in the dump that the $ oldTypesConges still corresponds to the new value

Comment: Yes i think this way `$oldTypesConges = clone $parametresAdmin->getTypesConges();`make a clone of method call unfortunately, so we need to create variable and clone it after. Take a loot at the updated post above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222071/discussion-between-lounis-and-kiuega).

Comment: Yes, I tried with your updated post, but same thing. I updated my first post with new current code

Answer (score 0):

Use session variables to store the old data:

To store your data before rendering the form in the controller, use:

`$this->get('session')->set('oldTypesConges ', $typesConges );`

And after submitting, read the data stored to compare it with the new one:

```
$oldTypesConges = $this->get('session')->get('oldTypesConges ');
```

Now, you can compare `$typesConges` and `$oldTypesConges`.

This solution was inspired from here: [How to set session variables for all the controllers in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682743/how-to-set-session-variables-for-all-the-controllers-in-symfony2/25683001)